# setting a variable to CGPointMake

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, variables, cgpoint

How can I set a variable to a `CGMakePoint`?

I've tried setting and calling the variable in the following ways:

I expected this one to work.

```
float p0[] = {0, 100};

UIBezierPath *point = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
    [point moveToPoint:CGPointMake(p0)]; // this tells me I need two arguments
```

Nope!

```
float *p0 = CGPointMake(0, 100);

UIBezierPath *point = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
    [point moveToPoint:p0];
```

Failed!

```
NSObject *p0 = CGPointMake(0, 100);

UIBezierPath *point = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
    [point moveToPoint:p0];
```

Another error!

```
id p0 = CGPointMake(0, 100);

UIBezierPath *point = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
    [point moveToPoint:p0];
```

Par for the course!

```
NSString *p0 = @"CGPointMake(0, 100)";

UIBezierPath *point = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
    [point moveToPoint:p0];
```

I'm guessing I am just casting it as the wrong type. I don't necessarily need to set my variable `= CGPointMake(0, 100)` but I do need to be able to set my variable to my coordinates `= (0, 100)`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was right... I was casing my variable as the wrong type. Once I set it to `CGPoint` it worked as expected.

```
CGPoint p0 = CGPointMake(0, 100);

UIBezierPath *point = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
    [point moveToPoint:p0];
```

Comment: haha, you were wrong, yet right. indeed! I think you should have accepted the other answer given as it was correct and he took the time to help you as well as give you an ace suggestion. cheers

Answer (score 9):

```
CGPoint myPoint = CGPointMake(10.0, 50.0);
```

But please, do yourself a favor and learn properly what you're doing. The problem you're facing is extremely basic, and if you're stuck at this level, there will be insurmountable problems soon.

I usually recommend the Big Nerd Ranch Guide books for beginners, but I'm not 100% sure if they start on a basic enough level for you.

This is not meant as an insult; merely as a friendly hint.

Comment: That's a bit mean. I have read the BNR books and I'm still learning. It's easy to miss some simple things as I learn but as you can see below I did figure it out for myself. As a flight medic I have a very in depth understanding of cardiology and ventilation and very simple principles to me can be very difficult for someone new. Please remember we all had to start somewhere and flaming a newb for asking a basic question really doesn't accomplish anything. I always try to do a search for my answer before asking a question but sometimes it's a matter knowing what to search for.

Comment: FYI... I had never even looked at objective-c prior to two months ago and unfortunately didn't even have a understanding of C at the time either. So I feel pretty good about where I've come in two months time. I do appreciate your help though. Please be patient with me as I learn. The "Xcode Primer" books by Nick Smith have been an excellent resource for someone as new as me. Prior to those the BNR books where even above my head.

Comment: @ShannonBuckland I don't want to speak for fzwo, but his counsel is prudent. It's not a criticism of you. But his suggestion is excellent. If you're stumbling over something this fundamental, you're going to have a long, tough slog, with lots of false starts and poorly designed apps. Avail yourself of the wonderful training materials out there. You're going to say yourself months of failed attempts if you get one or two programming resources under your belt (such as Stanford's online course, available free on iTunes, or any of a dozen other training sources such a Big Nerd Ranch Guide books).

Comment: Thanks @Rob for your feedback and the help in direction. I have read Nick Smith three "xCode primer" books and they have been a excellent resource. I have also read Big Nerd Ranch's "iOS Programming". I am currently working through Stanford's course as well. I understand it was a basic question but I'm asking questions because I do want to "learn properly what I'm doing." I feel like people sometimes assume that because a question was basic that someone hasn't put in the due diligence to try an find the answer through other resources before posting on stack exchange.

Comment: @ShannonBuckland Excellent, it sounds like you're doing the sort of training and research that one should. Unfortunately, these sorts of questions come from people who are jumping into the deep end of the pool without first learning how to swim, and we're just trying to help people from drowning. If we too quickly assumed you were in this category, I apologize, but hopefully you appreciate that the guidance came with the best of intentions. We've all been there at one point or another in our careers, and we just wanted to help.

Comment: Just to clear this up: @ShannonBuckland, I wasn't trying to be mean at all. I just thought I'd rather be helpful than deny yourself constructive criticism out of a false sense of politeness. I thought I'd made that clear.

Comment: No you were fine. After re-reading your post I realized it was constructive and appropriate. I just jumped because I was expecting to get flamed for asking such a basic question, so I was already on the defensive. I apologize for jumping to a conclusion and being defensive.